# Opening a different activity once the user Logs In

Tags: android, android-activity

I want that when the user opens the app for the first time after installation he gets an activity which asks him to make account. Once user makes account and he gets Homepage of his account. Now he closes the app. Opens it the next time. He should get the homepage and not the make account activity again. How can that be done?

Edit: I want to know where exactly i need to check my shared preferences. In the main activity's `onCreate`?

Answer (score 0):

Create a preferences object and store the status of registration in it.  Create an activity to register/make an account. Once account is made, store this in the preferences object and check this preferences object when the app is opened.  If its true, they registered and show the home page, if its false show the 'make account' activity.'  You could alternatively use a subclassed 'registration dialog' in the main activity instead of calling/writing another activity all together.

Answer (score 0):

First,Store user details on SharedPrefrences

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("logged",true)
editor.putString("username",username);
editor.commit();
```

Then you can choose either to make a Dispatcher Class like this

```
public class Dispatcher extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("prefs",MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (sharedPreferences != null) {
        if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("logged", false)) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        }
    } else {

        startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
    }
```

Or just implement this on the `onCreate()` method in LoginActivity

Comment: Thanks! But when it's installed for the first time it does the correct thing to open MainActivity.class. But on opening the app again it just shows a blank screen instead of the content of the Homepage.